# Jquery Datatable in bootstrap Modal Not reloading after modal close

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

HI i have a jquery data table in bootstrap modal, The data for the modal is from my **MODEL** class like,

```
<table id="demoGrid1" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" >  
                <thead>  
              <tr>  
                <th > Code</th>  
                <th>Description</th>      
                <th>Unit</th>  
                <th style="visibility:hidden"> Price</th>
                  <th style="visibility:hidden"> Color</th>
            </tr>  
                </thead>  
              <tbody>
                  @foreach (var item in Model)
                  {
                      <tr>
                          <td>@item.StockCode</td>
                          <td>@item.Description</td>
                          <td>@item.Unit</td>
                          <td style="visibility:hidden">@item.Price</td>
                          <td style="visibility:hidden">@item.Color</td>
                      </tr>
                  }
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

am calling this model by

```
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

and am hiding once the selection done

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

My issue when i make a selection in the datatable am applying some styles and all, which got not been clearing when i close and reopen the popup again, The selections, and styles are remaing the same even after i reopen my model.

I tried

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {

        $('#demoGrid1').DataTable().draw();
    });
```

to re draw the datatable, but didn't worked out. Please help me on this guys. How do i Redraw the datatable in the modal popup with defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `destroy()` method to remove features of DataTables enhancements and return the table to its original un-enhanced state, with the data in the table.

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
           var table = $('#demoGrid1').DataTable();
           table.destroy();
           $('#demoGrid1').empty(); // empty in case the columns change
           $('#demoGrid1').DataTable();
    });
```

Comment: It will destroy all my table data. My table is working like a selector popup. Once i call destroy all the columns and data.  $('#demoGrid1').DataTable(); will not rebuild it. As i said am not using Ajax for data. Its my model which gives the data to table.

Comment: The best Solution, You can as well convert the data table to fetch from the server side.

Comment: destroy() method only remove datatables features not data. do not use empty() method.

Comment: destroy() dosen't remove the items in the datatable serach box input